# Is SD card damaged

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, external-sd, sd-card, crashes

I bought 32GB SanDisk class 10/UHS1 SD card from Flipkart.com
Many times it fails to load all apps from SD card and many time it simply says in notifications "Damaged SD card", or suddenly notifies "Safe to remove SD card"!!! But it also loads all apps many times. What could be the reason?

Actually I inserted this SD card by first copy pasting the whole content of old SD card to it. Can this be the reason for such behavior? Should I clean format this SD card and then insert clean ed one and then let Android to format it? And make up a clean start?

Since in many instances it loads all apps, I am thinking it must not be damaged. But want some advice. Should I request Flipkart for re-shipping a new one?

Answer (score 1):

My friend had a similar problem, he went into the Verizon store and they just flat out gave him a new card, it took like 5 minutes. We were actually out of there so quickly he forgot to thank the lady behind the desk. His card was completely corrupted and he lost all of his files and such.

Your card seems to be partially corrupted or not corrupted at all. What I would do is copy all of the files from the SD card onto a backup drive and then flash a new SD card with your old SD card files.

### If the card still does not work:

at this point it almost has to be the files on the actual SD card. I would a couple files onto the SD card at a time until you find the corrupted file(s). Then you should delete the corrupted files, there isn't much you can do to restore them.

If you have a Mac, I am a fan of `DiskUtil`, it works really well even for fixing SD cards. I'm sure there is a similiar tool for Windows or Ubuntu.

Hope this helped!

Comment: What do you mean by `flash a new SD card`, just copy pasting the whole content? actually when I copy pasted old sd content to newer ones I realised that the size of pasted one was smaller than the first sd card content size, also I realized that this is [common problem](http://www.forbes.com/sites/sap/2011/04/28/is-your-android-smartphones-sd-card-causing-it-to-crash-or-lose-data/) in Android, is there any robust method to move sd card content from one to another? I believe copy pasting content is culprit here. Do u think the same?

Comment: I don't think copy/paste contents is the culprit. But it's known that some combinations of device/sdcard can cause problems. So if you can afford another card, try a different brand/model/class (e.g. a class-6 should be fast enough in 99% of all cases, so you might want to chose a class-6 of a different manufacturer), and see if your problems persist.

Comment: @Izzy is correct, class 6 SD cards are the most reliable and the most compatible. I would get the warranty on the card and try to replace it with a class 6.

Comment: @John now I tried to uninstall those apps that werent not loading (which I copied from older sd card) and installed them back from PlayStore and now they are working fine. I have tested if they get loaded even after rebooting the phone or reinserting the card. Can this be the reason that simply copy pasting old sd cards' content to the new one is not working on my phone

Comment: @Mahesha999 it might be working for now but it's possible that in the near future the card will become corrupted again. It is very possible you are using an SD card that is not compatible with your Android device.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd whip that thing out of your phone, pop it in an SD card reader connected to a laptop/desktop, backup the card, then erase and format it fully using the SD card formatting tool (v4) from the [SD Association](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/) and then test it thoroughly with H2testw 1.4 assuming you have a computer with Windows. There's an article which talks a bit about testing SD cards [here](http://sosfakeflash.wordpress.com/2008/09/02/h2testw-14-gold-standard-in-detecting-usb-counterfeit-drives/). I think there's another tool called F3 that can do something similar on a Mac if you've got one of those.

If you run into any errors along the way then you've probably got a dodgy card. If not then maybe you've got a compatibility problem with that card and your phone and I'd go with a slower card, and possibly a smaller one.

Best of luck!

Comment: But then what about re-copying data from the old SD card to the newly formatted SD card? How will you do that?